# .net dataset grid- rearranging the table columns dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataset

I have a dataset which I am populating on aspx page using gridview.
I want few of the rows to come as columns dynamically.
ex: i want all the fund numbers to come as columns(dynamically) and sum of percent salary in the value of those columns. also the annual rates for common name is summed up and shown as one single entry.

**My actual data**:

```
LastName  FirstName AnnualRate FundNumber  PercentSalary

AAA        AAA1      50000      201156      12

AAA        AAA1      40000      201156      6

BBB        BBB1      40000      201158      15

BBB        BBB1      40000      201160      20
```

**I want to make it like this:**

```
LastName  FirstName AnnualRate  201156     201158 201160

AAA       AAA1      90000        18%         0%     0%

BBB       BBB1      80000        0%          15%    20%
```

Please Help!!

Comment: Its really helpful if you format the question properly

Comment: in my actual data i have a column called "fund number" and all the fund numbers are listed into it viz. 201156, 201158, 201160. these may increase or change. i want them to come up as column names dynamically as i showed into my required data. how can we do that ?

Comment: you get this data from database?

Comment: i have this in my dataset

Comment: check my answer I have change it to use a data table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps to make this work.
Assume you have data table with data

```
DataTable ddt = getData();//dtt is your table from data set.
```

Step 1: convert table to list and filter some information we required

```
List<DataRow> data = ddt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
        var names = data.GroupBy(a => a["FirstName"]);//get names
        var fn = data.GroupBy(a => a["FundNumber"]);//get the FundNumbers
```

Step 2: Create a new DataTable with required columns.

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        tbl.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
        tbl.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
        tbl.Columns.Add("AnnualRate", typeof(string));
        foreach (var item in fn)
        {
            tbl.Columns.Add(item.Key.ToString(),typeof(string));
        }
```

Step 3: now add data to the table

```
foreach (var item in names)
        {
            List<DataRow> specificData = data.Where(d => d["FirstName"] == item.Key).ToList();
            DataRow newRow = tbl.NewRow();
            newRow["LastName"] = specificData[0]["LastName"];
            newRow["FirstName"] = item.Key;
            newRow["AnnualRate"] = specificData.Sum(s =>(int) s["AnnualRate"]);
            foreach (var val in fn)
            {
                newRow[val.Key.ToString()] = specificData.Where(s => s["FundNumber"] == val.Key).Sum(s => (int)s["PercentSalary"]) + "%";
            }

            tbl.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
```

Finally bind the data to your grid.

```
GridView1.DataSource = tbl;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```